# Cant perform multiple queries in a stored procedure without errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm building a web portal in ASP.NET that allows us to track some security events that happen in our environment that are fairly proprietary to our platform.

The data is really straight forward. We collect it and log it in a pretty basic table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblBonks]
(
    [bonkID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [bonkVictim] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [bonkMachineID] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [bonkUser] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [bonkTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblBonks] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

I have a stored procedure that my code calls to gather 24hr, 7day, and 1month stats. Depending I setup a single variable, @Scoreboard, that I can pass a string to to cause the stored procedure to generate different scoreboard stats.
This all seems pretty simple.

Here is the stored procedure as it exists now:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_BuildScoreboard 
     @ScoreBoard nvarchar(25),
     @Day nvarchar(5) OUTPUT,
     @Week nvarchar(5) OUTPUT,
     @Month  nvarchar(5) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (@ScoreBoard = 'VICTIM')
    BEGIN
        set @Day = (select TOP(1) bonkVictim, count(bonkVictim) as bonknumber
                    from tblBonks
                    where bonkTime > DATEADD(DAY, -1, SYSDATETIME()) 
                      and bonkVictim != bonkUser
                    group by bonkVictim
                    order by bonknumber desc)

        /* 7 days */
        set @Week = (select TOP(1) bonkVictim, count(bonkVictim) as bonknumber
                     from tblBonks
                     where bonkTime > DATEADD(WEEK, -1, SYSDATETIME()) 
                       and bonkVictim != bonkUser
                     group by bonkVictim
                     order by bonknumber desc)

        /* 1 month */
        set @Month = (select TOP(1) bonkVictim, count(bonkVictim) as bonknumber
                      from tblBonks
                      where bonkTime > DATEADD(MONTH, -1, SYSDATETIME()) 
                        and bonkVictim != bonkUser
                      group by bonkVictim
                      order by bonknumber desc)
    END
    /*ELSE IF (@ScoreBoard = 'LEADER')
    BEGIN
    END
    ELSE IF (@ScoreBoard = 'MACHINE')
    BEGIN
    END*/
END
GO
```

However I have learned that this doesn't work for some reason. These should be three independent queries that return their own value to the output variables.

I get this error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_BuildScoreboard, Line 38
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
>
> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_BuildScoreboard, Line 41
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
>
> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_BuildScoreboard, Line 42
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I'm super weak in T-SQL. Searching for those errors tends to take me into some other issues that aren't completely related to mine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get in the habit of putting semicolons at the end of each statement.  That's not the problem (in this case).  Instead, write syntactically correct statements:

```
       set @Day = (select TOP(1) bonkVictim
                   from tblBonks
                   where bonkTime > DATEADD(DAY, -1, SYSDATETIME()) and
                          bonkVictim <> bonkUser
                    group by bonkVictim
                    ORDER BY count(bonkVictim) desc
                   );
```

Note that the subquery is a *scalar subquery*.  It can return only one column and at most one row.  Two columns should generate an error.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on syntax.  And the rewrite of my query. Updated like your example it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `bonkVictim,` from each `select` statement, so that the select statements only return one row and one column.